# Associated models not passing validation errors to parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am currently building a Rails App and I have two associated models.
Subnets and devices, the devices are inside the subnets. Both do some degree of validation.

```
class Subnet < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :devices , dependent: :destroy

  validates_presence_of :devices

  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :CIDR, presence: true
  validates_associated :devices
end



class Device < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :subnet

  validates :subnet, :presence => true

  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: {scope: :subnet_id}
  validates :IP, presence: true, uniqueness: {scope: :subnet_id}
 end
```

When trying to create a new device, which already exists, this new device will not be created - which is supposed to work like that.
Although, I would like some kind of error message displayed after this incident, but my code doesn't seem to hand over the errors from child to parent.
The relevant part of my view for the subnets (which also contains the error handling) looks like this:

```
...
<% if @subnet.errors.any? %>     <-------- This line seems to not get the information about the failed validation of the device
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2>
      <%= pluralize(@subnet.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
      this subnet from being saved:
    </h2>
    <ul>
      <% @subnet.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>

<h2>Add a device:</h2>
<%= form_with(model: [ @subnet, @subnet.devices.build ], local: true) do |form| %>
  <p>
    <%= form.label :name %><br>
    <%= form.text_field :name %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= form.label :IP %><br>
    <%= form.text_field :IP %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= form.label :notes %><br>
    <%= form.text_area :notes %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>  
...
```

And the create function for the devices from the device_controller looks like this:

```
def create
    @subnet = Subnet.find(params[:subnet_id])
    @device = @subnet.devices.create(device_params)
    redirect_to subnet_path(@subnet)
end
```

How can I get my `subnet show view` to react to the errors from the devices?

Comment: Is your association being assigned?  From [API Dock](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_associated): "NOTE: This validation will not fail if the association hasn’t been assigned. If you want to ensure that the association is both present and guaranteed to be valid, you also need to use `validates_presence_of`".

Comment: why do you want `subnet` to show any error if the error is on `device`. Your subnet already exists so there is no reason for this. If you redirect to a subnet show view after device creation, just set errors for devices on the subnet view: `<% if @device.errors.any? %>`

Comment: @TomAranda : I added the `validates_presence_of` but nothing changed, so I think the models are associated correctly  

@Maxence : My devices are a part of the subnets, so I can't acces `@device` in my subnet view. It tells me "undefined method ´errors´ for nil:NilClass when I put `<% if @device.errors.any? %>` instead of the subnet check